# Using Entity Framework 6.1 (prerelease) IdentityUser with integer ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

In the new Entity Framework 6.1 beta/pre-release they have included the option to change the datatype of the `Id` column that is used within the database. I am looking into how this should be implemented and have come to the following:

#### ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, IdentityUserLogin<int>,
IdentityUserRole<int>, IdentityUserClaim<int>>, IObjectState
{
}
```

#### AuthenticationContext.cs

```
public class AuthenticationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int, IdentityUserRole<int>>, int, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityUserRole<int>, IdentityUserClaim<int>>
{
    public AuthenticationContext()
        : base("ConnectionString")
    {
    }
}
```

#### AccountController.cs

```
public AccountController() : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int, IdentityUserRole<int>>, int, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityUserRole<int>, IdentityUserClaim<int>>(new AuthenticationContext())))
{
}

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}

public UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

When running the application (which is the default EF/MVC app) I get the following errors when clicking Register:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole2[System.Int32,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole1[System.Int32]]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.`

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I'm unsure what I should adjust to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have your EF model in a seperate project/dll than your main web project?

Comment: Yes, they reside in a seperate Class Library (`Project.Entities`). The context also resides in another different project (`Project.Data`).

Comment: Start off with the example in the link in my answer, ie. each GuidRole etc as it's own class that inherits from IdentityXX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try following this example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx under "Make the type of Primary Key be extensible for Users and Roles".
The difference is that you create separate classes for each identity model.

Comment: Indeed! the custom key (of Guid in my case) has started to work after creating derived entity classes. Note: In case you want to use Guid and want to allow Identity 2.0 to generate new IDs (as provided in the vanila version) you need to add a default constructor to your `ApplicationUser` (and `CustomRole` types) to initialize the Id property: `this.Id = Guid.NewGuid()`. This way you won't need a default value of NewID() (GUID/UUID) configured in your database Id columns.